# timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 gives unexpected behavior

Tags: virtualbox, systemd, time

The hardware clock in my virtual machine is the local time reported by my host (the local time is 10:14, but my VM incorrectly reports 6:14 as the local time):

[image]

When I use `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`, the local time of the VM does not change. For whatever reason, `set-local-rtc` changes the RTC time, rather than reversing/advancing the local time appropriately:

[image]

How do I get the local time in my VM to accurately reflect the local time of the host, given that the hypervisor is reporting a HW clock as the local time?

**Update:**

I tried running sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 0` for good measure, and that just sets the RTC back to the local time:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Updated :**
That will solved with,

```
sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

Comment: Still does not work. Local time is *still* set to 6:14.

Comment: what that's said output sir?

Comment: The same as the first screenshot (well, 6:25 since time goes on, I can't seem to post an image in the comments)

Comment: just edit your question with output, try restart your VB sir

Comment: Added to the original question

Comment: i have idea, try installing the system using [packer] (https://www.packer.io/), and remove line "d-i time/zone string UTC".

Comment: I am setting the timezone already in my preseed file: `d-i time/zone string America/New_York`

Comment: I noticed that I had `d-i clock-setup/utc boolean` set to `true`. I am going to change it to `false` to see what happens.

Comment: what's the output said if it set to boolean false sir?

Comment: Seemed to have made no difference. `timedatectl` reports exactly what was in the first screenshot.

Comment: Aha! Figured it out. I needed to add `--adjust-system-clock` to `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` like so: `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock`.

Comment: don't forget to restart your VB after change clock-setup/utc-auto boolean to false, sir

Comment: yeah, congratulation sir.

Comment: if that's solved, checked my answered sir, cause another user know how to solved that sir.

Comment: I also got around this by adding `"vboxmanage": ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--rtcuseutc", "on"]` to the `virtualbox-iso` builder in my packer JSON file. This tells VirtualBox to use UTC to set the virtual real time clock. Honestly not sure why VirtualBox doesn't do this by default for Unix-like guests.

Comment: I think not all virtual is real time, so there are additions arguments for that