# Ubuntu keeps displaying UTC time despite setting timezone

Tags: unity, virtualbox, time

Something appears to be broken with regards to how Unity displays the system time in the current time zone. I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 guest in VirtualBox, on a Windows 10 host. I have changed the timezone by linking `/etc/localtime` to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York` (because `sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York` didn't do anything). When I execute `timedatectl`, it reports the proper time and timezone:

```
$ timedatectl
      Local time: Mon 2018-11-12 10:54:13 EST
  Universal time: Mon 2018-11-12 15:54:13 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2018-11-12 15:54:12
       Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

However, for whatever reason, Unity is *still* incorrectly reporting the time in UTC time, even after rebooting the VM:

[image]

How do I get Unity to properly display the time in the local timezone?

Comment: have you tried setting your timezone from the settings gui?

Comment: Yes, but it had no effect.

Comment: i think you forgot to add a argument `--adjust-system-clock`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to reconfigure timezone data.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Comment: Holy frick that did it. I am going to run through the same steps to ensure that solved the problem.

Comment: confirmed this worked for me on AWS ec2 ubuntu distribution. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings > Time % Date  and set your location (in my case Paris)

[image]

The select the Clock tab and check both Time in auto-detected and Time in other locations. Then select <kbd>Choose Location</kbd> and add in (say) UTC or any other location you may require.

[image]

Then you will be able to select the time and date on the top bar with left clock of the mouse and select which time you wish to have displayed.

[image]

Comment: @wheeler If this answer solved the issue for you, perhaps you might be kind enough to mark it off as the best answer which will aid other users with similar issues. Thankyou.

Comment: Performing the steps you have outlined had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Command: To set to local time

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

To check:

```
timedatectl | grep local
```

Comment: The system clock is not in local time, as noted by the screenshot of `timedatectl`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem's you are using a NTP to synchronized your time/data. disable it with following

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove
```

and activated again your `systemd-timesyncd.service` like your [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064186/timedatectl-set-local-rtc-1-gives-unexpected-behavior) previously.

and do a alternative from the following material [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1310). set your UTC with following command on your Ubuntu 16.04 Guest

```
VBoxManage setextradata "your-VM-name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/UseUTC" 1
```

Finally, restart your VB again!!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Running `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock` yields `Failed to set local RTC: Access denied`.

Comment: @wheeler as mentions the output of your command `timedatectl`, you get `: Access denied` couse not yet activated your RTC, did you try my answered?

Comment: Your answer is not clear. I tried disabling NTP with the first command, and then ran `timedatectl set-local-rtc ...`